# Android Studio: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames

Tags: java, android, multithreading, processor, hal

I am getting an error in Android Studio, app cannot communicate with other app and two emulators working simultaneously use almost 100% of the processor.

I am not getting any errors except `Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames`. What can I do in this situation?
I have a feeling its a problem with emulator which is too slow, is that true?

Here's my log:

```
04-18 16:57:56.583 1382-1435/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4321429 , only wrote 4168800
04-18 16:57:57.005 9136-9147/com.example.matt.rider I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20288(877KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(96KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 14MB/14MB, paused 17.734ms total 501.934ms
04-18 16:57:57.289 9136-9147/com.example.matt.rider I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5087(243KB) AllocSpace objects, 13(2MB) LOS objects, 26% free, 11MB/15MB, paused 14.179ms total 261.011ms
04-18 16:57:58.703 2420-2432/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16895(1821KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 11MB/15MB, paused 9.655ms total 103.726ms
04-18 16:57:59.663 1382-1434/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4169071 , only wrote 4168800
04-18 16:57:59.714 1382-1434/? W/audio_hw_generic: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames
04-18 16:57:59.726 1382-1434/? W/audio_hw_generic: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames
```

Answer (score 0):

LOS for Large Object Space... it is possible for Java objects used by native code to be kept alive for too long. Some objects on the Java heap may become unreachable

see if this documentation can help
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#LogMessages